# Helper comment text for product attributes

Tags: product-attribute

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to create comment help text for custom product attributes (or really for any product attributes - even some core attributes could use some helper text to make it a bit more clear what they do).

What I mean by comment help text is for example what you get when you use `<comment>` in `system.xml`.
[image: system.xml comment help text]

So, for example, let's say you wanted to add a comment under *Meta Title* in the *Meta Information* tab of a product edit page to say "This is what will show up in the browser title bar".

I just noticed that *Meta Description* as an example already has some comment help text ("Maximum 255 chars") underneath it, but from a quick glance I'm not seeing where that would be defined under the Attribute details under *Catalog* > *Manage Attributes* > *meta_description*

I haven't done much digging yet into the core code to hunt for this yet, so my apologies if this is a really stupid question!

Comment: I'd look pretty hard at the setup script / default entities definition which creates that attribute in the first place. I'd check myself but I'm installing osx. Again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ha...this is a good one.
The field in the db that determines the text under the attribute field is `note` from the `eav_attribute` table.
I never noticed that you can't change that from the UI.
I've created a lot of attributes that have a 'comment' below the fields but never change one.

To add that you need to specify this in the install script:

```
$this->addAttribtue('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here', array(
   ....
   'note' => 'This will be displayed below the field',
   ....
));
```

To change it for one attribute you can add this in an install/upgrade script.

```
$this->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here', 'note', 'This will be displayed below the field');
```

I can't believe that I've missed this in all the million versions I've used so far.

**[EDIT]**
See the definition of the `meta_description` attribute in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup::installEntities()`.

```
'meta_description'   => array(
                        'type'                       => 'varchar',
                        'label'                      => 'Meta Description',
                        'input'                      => 'textarea',
                        'required'                   => false,
                        'note'                       => 'Maximum 255 chars',
                        'class'                      => 'validate-length maximum-length-255',
                        'sort_order'                 => 3,
                        'global'                     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group'                      => 'Meta Information',
                    ),
```

Comment: I see what's going on here.  This goes back to what Vinai said about never creating these things manually - it's better to create them all with setup scripts.  I still do them manually b/c I'm not managing a lot of them at a time, so I can get away with it.  This is another good reason to move to always creating attribs programatically.

Comment: My proposal on Twitter was to add an UI to view / update the `note` field. I've already implemented this and ready to send a PR against at least Magento 1.x

Comment: it also works in magento2 with the 'note' field.